How to retrieve the Network Access IP ranges via SFDX?
I would like to retrieve IP ranges from Network Access via SFDX but I don't how I can retrieve this? I don't see this as an option anywhere from the Salesforce Object Reference doc.

sf project retrieve start -m IPAddressRange

Will retrieve the IPAddressRange object, which represents the Network Access ranges.
It's not a "standard object" in the usual sense (Account, Contact), but instead is a type of metadata.

Thanks sfdcfox, I thought it could have been IPAddressRange too however, when I try to retrieve this from my org which has about 20 IP addresses, I see 'Retrieved Source: No results found' message.
I am using: sfdx force:source:retrieve -m IPAddressRange -u [mySandboxAlias]

The IP Address range is contained within Security settings and can be retrieved like so:
sf project retrieve start -m Settings:Security -o <orgalias/username>
You can deploy changes to just the ipRanges by doing a minimal XML deploy like so:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <networkAccess>
        <ipRanges>
            <description>This is just a test range</description>
            <end>192.168.255.255</end>
            <start>192.168.0.1</start>
        </ipRanges>
    </networkAccess>
</SecuritySettings>

Run the command:
sf project deploy start --source-dir ./path-to-file/settings/Security.settings-meta.xml -o <orgalias/username>
